# How to disable squiggly lines underline in VSC 1.49.2?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Please help, it's driving me nuts. I tried following another older stack overflow post and it didn't work. I just declare a new variable and I already get squiggly line -  what an annoying feature. Using python by the way on VSC.

Something like this:

[image: Example]

My json.settings look like this:
[image: json.settings]

Comment: Could you provide us with the variable declaration code you use and the related error message or screenshots?

Comment: @JillCheng I just added an example screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I reproduced the problem.

The reason is that Python's code analysis tool Pylint detects that the variable "`words_to_remove`" is not used, so it displays "`Pylint(Unused variable)`".

Solution:

1. Complete the code. for example:

   [image]
2. Turn off the prompt of Pylint.

   1). Close the "[Unused variable](https://github.com/janjur/readable-pylint-messages/blob/master/README.md#w0612---unused-variable-r)" prompt of pylint:

   Please use `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable=W0612"],` in `settings.json`:

   [image]

   2). Close Pylint.

   Use `"python.linting.enabled":false ,` in settings.json.

In addition, Pylint is an excellent Python code analysis tool. It will provide good suggestions on the format and syntax of the code we edit and it does not affect the execution of the code.

Therefore, if you want to turn off Pylint related prompts to remove the wavy lines, it is better to set it off after the code can be executed.

Comment: Where is json.settings do I add these lines? Could you show me please?

Comment: Okay, think I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @thiri -For more content of "settings.json" in VSCode, you could refer to [it](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).